# Coordinates do not display correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, display

I have a table with coordinates of some postcodes and I want to display them in ArcMap. The points should be on the street centrelines. When I bring in the csv file and right click to display the points, they are being located on the properties instead of the street centrelines. I have nearly 5000 records in the table so I have to find a automated way to deal with this.

Does anyone knows what tool to run to bring the point onto the centrelines?

Comment: Search snap point to line

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. This is the error message that comes in when I try to run the snap poin to line tool: `The value is not a member of END | VERTEX | EDGE.`

Comment: Convert your event points to actual feature dataset, e.g. right click - export to shapefile

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000007000000).  If you are not familiar with the concept there is a tutorial [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/linear-referencing-tutorial.pdf).

Basically the process will create a route from your roads with M values, which represent the points along the route.  It is probably best you read up on it.  The desription of how the tool works is best.  Note the warnings about using very large search radii around the points to detect the routes.